# Kotlin BLE Can't discover Characteristics

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Kotlin and Android.
I need to write an app that finds a particular peripheral, connects to it and writes to a characteristic.

I can find it, and I am connecting to it and finding services.

However, I can not seem to discover an characteristics at all.

Code:

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)

    mClientActionListener.log("** Made it to onServicesDiscovered")

    if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        mClientActionListener.log("Device service discovery unsuccessful, status $status")

        return
    }

    mClientActionListener.log("BLE Service status: $status. What we are looking for: $gatt")

    val matchingCharacteristics = bluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt)
...

fun findCharacteristics(bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt): List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> {
    Log.i(TAG_BLEUTIL, "** Made it to findCharacteristics")
    val matchingCharacteristics = ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>()

    val serviceList = bluetoothGatt.services
    Log.i(TAG_BLEUTIL, "** serviceList: $serviceList")

    val characteristics = bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(serviceList[1].characteristics[0])
    Log.i(TAG_GATT_CALLBACK, "** Characteristics: $characteristics")

    val service = findService(serviceList) ?: return matchingCharacteristics

    val characteristicList = service.characteristics
    Log.i(TAG_BLEUTIL, "characterList: $characteristicList")

    for (characteristic in characteristicList) {
            matchingCharacteristics.add(characteristic)
    }

    Log.i(TAG_BLEUTIL, "Characteristics: $matchingCharacteristics")

    return matchingCharacteristics
}
```

Logs from a typical run:

```
... D/PairState: Device004
... I/PairState: 00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1
... D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
... I/PairState: ** Connecting to VQpa004
... I/BleService: Connecting to 00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1
... I/BleService: onConnectionStateChange newState: 2
... D/BleGattServerCallback: onConnectionStateChange newState: 2
... I/BleService: Connected to device 00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1
... D/BleGattServerCallback: BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED: 0
... D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1
... D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
... D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1 Status=0
... I/BleService: ** Made it to onServicesDiscovered
... I/BleService: BLE Service status: 0. What we are looking for: android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@9917c65
... I/BluetoothUtils: ** Made it to findCharacteristics
... I/BluetoothUtils: ** serviceList: [android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService@1f6ed3a, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService@746ddeb, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService@f8c4748]
... I/BleGattServerCallback: ** Characteristics: false
... I/BluetoothUtils: ** Made it to findService
... D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=00:23:A7:FD:2B:B1 interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
```

From what I am understanding from the docs as well as some other (Java oriented) posts here on SO this code should be working.  But I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for the help.  I'm glad to offer more code if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  The main problem was that I was a expecting the Android BLE libs/flow to be similar to iOS.

Some things to keep in mind when doing BLE on Android that fixed the problem for me:

1. There is no call to discover characteristics (like in iOS).  Once you reach onServicesDiscovered in Android, you are expected to operate on the services and characteristics directly.

e.g.

```
for (characteristic in matchingCharacteristics) {
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT)
        enableCharacteristicNotification(gatt, characteristic)
    }
```

That's kind of a non-typical use but the basic principle is: Once you have the services you are passed a GATT profile that has all the services, characteristics and descriptors in it.  From there you can operate on all of them directly without any further discovery.  See the Android docs for the functions that are available to the BluetoothGattCharacteristic once the services are found.

2. The line I used above to get the services:
   mClientActionListener.log("BLE Service status: $status. What we are looking for: $gatt")
   Was actually sending back the characteristics NOT the services.  This was confusing me because the BLE peripheral that I was testing agains had only one service and three characteristics associated with it.  But the fact that we were inside onServicesDiscovered when pulling the information and the fact that I did not catch that the gatt object was actually a GATT profile with more in it than the services, and the syntax confused me into thinking that I should be expecting only services at that point
   ** Remember: when you are in onServicesDiscovered you get everything in the GATT object passed back to you.
3. There are some functions that will let you discover characteristics and other information from there on. However, they are there for informational purposes.  They don't give you anymore exposure to the characteristics or descriptors.

I leave it up to your to decide if this is a good way to do something that is async and a bit "guns and whiskey" to begin with.  But it's the way it is in Android.

Code clean.  Code smart.